# How expensive is it to access an object property of a large object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Background: I am a mostly self-taught programmer. I've been doing professional JS work for the last six years, but because of my lack of familiarity with computer science fundamentals, some things are not clear to me.

Considering the object:

```
const test = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

you could find the value of property `b` in two ways. Path 1:

```
console.log(test.b)
```

or, alternatively, Path 2:

```
for( const prop of Object.keys(test) ){
    if( prop === 'b' ) return console.log(test[prop])
}
```

**My question:** under the hood, is doing Path 1 essentially the same as Path 2? Does the computer still have to look through every property of `test` to find `b`? Or does it somehow "magically" know where exactly to look in the memory when it gets `test[b]` so it doesn't have to scan through the entire object?

Comment: Path1 is different to path2. I think it depends on what JS engine is being used, but for chrome, you can find details on how path1 is done here: https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties. I think if you want a basic level understanding you can look at [hash-tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20hash%20table,desired%20value%20can%20be%20found.) (although V8 apparently doesn't use these, it will give you an understanding on how fast/constant look-up can be achieved)

Comment: The implementation depends on the JS engine being used, but I think it's pretty safe to say they will mostly use a HashTable so that accessing elements would be in O(1) complexity (meaning you don't have to loop through all the properties) so Path1 would be faster because it's direct access, it's not magic :) here is how hashtables work https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: In addition, implementations have caching mechanisms so they don't have to repeat the hash function when they access the same property multiple times. Objects are a critical data structure, and implementations optimize them as best as they can.

Comment: I think something that helps with questions about performance is an attempt to compare performance itself.  Use profiling tools and compare the run times of using direct property access vs the second method.  Add your results and assumptions.  We then have a place to jump off from because we can either narrow the performance test or help correct or affirm the assumptions.  [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/) is great for this, but there are client side tools as well.

Comment: You can also access 'b' in an array-like syntax without the loop: `test['b']`. Equivalent to `test.b` in every way and doesn't require a loop. Looping over `Object.keys` is certainly slower than not doing one, but JIT compilers might mitigate this problem if they use some optimization.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, definitely in the second example, the time interval, however small, has been created
Because you used a loop, and in any case, each of these keys will be looped, and any key that matches your conditions will be selected, so the time interval is created, however small, and the goal of the first example is clear, and it goes directly to the same answer.

> And in my opinion and according to my experience

Accessing an object's property in JavaScript usually does not have a significant performance impact unless it involves computationally heavy tasks such as dealing with very large objects or large-scale nested loops. If you have a very large object, it may take some time for JavaScript to search through its properties, but in general, the impact is minimal.